# Unable to install mysqlclient on centos

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am building a django app and for which i need to configure mysql.I am trying to install mysqlclient module for sql connection and this is what i am trying

```
pip install mysqlclient --no-cache-dir
```

It is throwing me following error.It is throwing error while linking to gcc library.

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz (89kB)
    100% |################################| 92kB 4.0MB/s 
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /home/admin/awx.varadev.com/awxenv/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6m2TNP/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-WFoARo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/admin/awx.varadev.com/awxenv/include/site/python2.7/mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
    In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:6:0,
                     from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
                     from _mysql.c:32:
    /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig-64.h:1188:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
     #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
     ^
    In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:25:0,
                     from /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:38,
                     from _mysql.c:29:
    /usr/include/features.h:168:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     # define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
     ^
    In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:6:0,
                     from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
                     from _mysql.c:32:
    /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig-64.h:1210:0: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
     #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
     ^
    In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:25:0,
                     from /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:38,
                     from _mysql.c:29:
    /usr/include/features.h:170:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     # define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
     ^
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -lmariadb -lpthread -lz -ldl -lm -lssl -lcrypto -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmariadb
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/admin/awx.varadev.com/awxenv/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6m2TNP/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-WFoARo-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/admin/awx.varadev.com/awxenv/include/site/python2.7/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6m2TNP/mysqlclient/
```

is this gcc default feature to link a library file for mysql? I have googled on this and it showing that gcc needs as **.so** file which i need to symlink with some location.I am running mariadb 10.9 on my server and i did not find any such file in my system.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't get the client from the CentOS package repository (e.g. via `yum install MySQL-python`) instead of installing through pip?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Solved in CentOS 7 + MariaDB 10.2

I'm having same issue, and **I would like to contribute with my answer**. I've just installed in my 2 servers running CentOS 7 with MariaDB (10.2.14-MariaDB MariaDB Server)
.

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

$ mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is XXXX
Server version: 10.2.14-MariaDB MariaDB Server
```

I've installed MariaDB, this packages:

```
$ yum list installed | grep mariadb
MariaDB-client.x86_64                   10.3.13-1.el7.centos           @mariadb
MariaDB-common.x86_64                   10.3.13-1.el7.centos           @mariadb
MariaDB-compat.x86_64                   10.3.13-1.el7.centos           @mariadb
MariaDB-server.x86_64                   10.3.13-1.el7.centos           @mariadb
galera.x86_64                           25.3.25-1.rhel7.el7.centos     @mariadb
```

I found that the problem is that mysqlclient requires mysql-devel packages, which is different from mariadb-devel. **Don't install mariadb-devel!**

So, to install only mysql-devel, you need to:

#### 1. Remove any MariaDB-devel

```
$ sudo yum erase MariaDB-devel.x86_64
```

#### 2. Add MySQL repository in yum

1. Go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/ and select the RPM file for your CentOS (for me, I choose *"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 / Oracle Linux 7 (Architecture Independent), RPM Package"*. Click *"download"*.)
2. Download without registration, copy bottom link *"No thanks, just start my download"*.
3. Go to your terminal and type:

```
$ wget link-to-rpm-you-choose
```

4. After download complete, type:

```
$ sudo rpm -Uvh your-rpm-downloaded
```

#### 3. Now, install mysql-devel

1. Type (this is my version, watch yours):

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-community-devel.x86_64
```

#### 4. Now, finally: mysqlclient

1. Type:

```
$  sudo pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz (85kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 758kB/s
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... done
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

### And that's it! It worked like a charm and now I can use Python + Django + MariaDB/MySQL

Oh, and mysqlclient is the connector recommended by Django. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

Good luck and see ya! :-)

Answer (score 8):

I found this solution at https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/issues/197:

The MariaDB-devel-10.2.6-1.fc25.x86_64 package contains only a library named:

```
/usr/lib64/libmariadbclient.a
```

However their pkg-config yields another name:

```
> pkg-config --libs mariadb
    -lmariadb
```

A workaround is to symlink libmariadbclient.a to libmariadb.a:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libmariadbclient.a /usr/lib64/libmariadb.a
```

Basically to have mysqlclient install in Python 3.6 and CentOS 7 you need to run:

```
sudo yum install -y python36-devel mysql-devel gcc

sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libmariadbclient.a /usr/lib64/libmariadb.a

pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution that worked for me is:

```
yum install python-devel mysql-devel
```

Then install mysqlclient using pip

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using CentOS 7.9.2009. and MariaDB version: 10.11.2-MariaDB. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's complaining about not being able to find mariadb libs. Run the following to find out why:

```
ld -lmariadb --verbose
```

This should tell you specifically what gcc is missing.

My guess is that you are missing some MySQL development headers. Install them with:

```
debian / ubuntu: sudo apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
redhat / centos: sudo yum install python-devel mysql-devel
```

Update: It really is missing MariaDB shared libs. I think on CentOS, this should take care of it:

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-devel
```

Final Update: Just use PyMySQL - pure python, no headers required, no need to jump through these kinds of hoops.

Comment: My question is how to install all these files not to check whether this is installed or not because this command is giving me  this ```cannot find -lzlib```

Comment: I mistyped the ld commend - try it again :)

Comment: Sorry but no success.got this response :
```Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Package python-devel-2.7.5-58.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package MariaDB-devel-10.2.9-1.el7.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do```

Comment: ```ld: cannot find -lmariadb```

Comment: @AtulAgrawal - I guess then you need to install them - I updated my answer but `sudo yum install MariaDB-devel`

Comment: still no success got this:-
```Package MariaDB-devel-10.2.9-1.el7.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do```

Comment: OK then I'd give up and just use pure python MySQL libs: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155630/discussion-between-atul-agrawal-and-danielle-m).

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal or login to the workstation/laptop/dev-server using ssh client. Type the following command yum command as a root user:

```
# yum install mysql
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * extras: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * updates: bay.uchicago.edu
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.71-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package         Arch             Version                  Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql           x86_64           5.1.71-1.el6             base           893 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 893 k
Installed size: 2.4 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
mysql-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                            | 893 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : mysql-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64                                    1/1 
  Verifying  : mysql-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64                                    1/1 

Installed:
  mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.71-1.el6                                                   

Complete!
```

mysql client the basic syntax is:

```
mysql -u USER-NAME-HERE -h MYSQL-DB-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS-HERE -p DB-NAME
mysql -u nixcraft -h server1.cyberciti.biz -p salesdata
```

Comment: This is response that i got ```Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Package MariaDB-client-10.2.9-1.el7.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do```

Comment: put the following locale relating setting in /etc/bashrc (for all users, bash):

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE=C
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
then run:

source /etc/bashrc
or log off and log on.

Answer (score 0):

After this:

```
sudo yum install mariadb-devel
```

I was able to install mysql client with:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Environment: Centos 7, MariaDB