# Cannot install mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, pip

I am using python3.8 in django framework, for that I have to install mysqlclient. But error is coming when I try

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

output like this as error.

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/97/7326248ac8d5049968bf4ec708a5d3d4806e412a42e74160d7f266a3e03a/mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/LPython/my_env/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fgg27tgk/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fgg27tgk/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-fgg27tgk/mysqlclient/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-fgg27tgk/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/LPython/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
      File "/home/LPython/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 35, in <module>
        from setuptools import windows_support
      File "/home/LPython/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved. When I installed python-3.8.0, I did not compile it, that was the problem. I am using Centos7, so I went to the root of the terminal, first install prerequisites for Python before installing it.

```
# sudo yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel

download latest version

#wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz

Now extract the downloaded package.

Compile Python Source

#cd Python-3.8.0
#sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations

make altinstall is used to prevent replacing the default python binary file /usr/bin/python.

#sudo make altinstall

remove downloaded source archive file from your system

#sudo rm Python-3.8.0.tgz

Check Python Version

#python3.8 -V 

Then I could be able to install mysqlclient by
# pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 13):

I think  **libffi-dev** libary file is missing in your system/server.
use the below command in order to check library installed or not

```
apt-cache search libffi
```

to install **libffi-dev**

```
sudo apt-get install -y libffi-dev
```

After that try

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Approach 2

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: Package libffi-devel-3.0.13-18.el7.x86_64 already installed. But still error is coming...

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
pip install mysqlclient

Comment: The above prerequisites i have already installed from https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/. But still error is coming..

Comment: Approach 2 worked for me after replacing pip by pip3

Comment: A mixture of both approaches worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'` occurring because of python [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue31652). In latest version of python this bug was solved.

- There for you have to update your pip
- Next you have to run this `yum install libffi-deve` or `sudo dnf install libffi-devel`
- After that run `pip3 install mysqlclient` or `sudo yum install python36u-devel mysql-devel` to install mysqlclient.

Comment: MariaDB-client is already installed. But I need mysqlclient apart from mysql driver. I don't have coda.

Comment: I am using centos 7

Comment: Do I need to set **libffi** any specific locations?

Comment: No, Don't give any location

Comment: Package **libffi-devel-3.0.13-18.el7.x86_64** already installed and latest version                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                     No package python36u-devel available.
Package MariaDB-devel-10.1.43-1.el7.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: This error totally base on  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'` If my any solutions didn't work read these two https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1183   https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/94#issuecomment-877227

Comment: And also take time and follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495448/unable-to-install-mysqlclient-on-centos/46495507

Comment: what you have said is correct. it was the bug of python. So i reinstall python and compile it. Then it works.

Comment: If any one of these answers right. Mark it as accepted. If not write your own answer and mark it as accepted. It will help other users who are having this issue