# Failed to install mysqlclient on Python3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, mysql-connector

When I input the command `pip3 install mysqlclient` in the terminal

I got the errors shown below:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-txq296uc
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/
```

Why did this error happen and how do I solve it?

-------------------------------the whole error report---------------------------------------

```
[root: ~]$ pip3 install mysqlclient
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/3c/df/59cd2fa5e48d0804d213bdcb1acb4d08c403b61c7ff7ed4dd4a6a2deb3f7/mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 88 kB 44 kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-txq296uc
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/
  Complete output (44 lines):
  mysql_config --version
  ['8.0.22']
  mysql_config --libs
  ['-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '-lmysqlclient', '-lpthread', '-lz', '-lm', '-lrt', '-lssl', '-lcrypto', '-ldl', '-lresolv']
  mysql_config --cflags
  ['-I/usr/include/mysql']
  ext_options:
    library_dirs: ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
    libraries: ['mysqlclient', 'pthread', 'm', 'rt', 'dl', 'resolv']
    extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
    extra_link_args: []
    include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql']
    extra_objects: []
    define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,0,3,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.0.3')]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,3,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c:46:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     46 | #include "Python.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-zx3xzsmt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/
    Complete output (44 lines):
    mysql_config --version
    ['8.0.22']
    mysql_config --libs
    ['-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '-lmysqlclient', '-lpthread', '-lz', '-lm', '-lrt', '-lssl', '-lcrypto', '-ldl', '-lresolv']
    mysql_config --cflags
    ['-I/usr/include/mysql']
    ext_options:
      library_dirs: ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      libraries: ['mysqlclient', 'pthread', 'm', 'rt', 'dl', 'resolv']
      extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
      extra_link_args: []
      include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql']
      extra_objects: []
      define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,0,3,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.0.3')]
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,3,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:46:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       46 | #include "Python.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j8wmao0g/mysqlclient_4fc64ccb15c04e9a9f90953983dcc696/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-zx3xzsmt/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory` could be a clue. Installing Python headers might help. They’re usually in a package called something like `python3-dev`, depending on your OS’s package manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install mysqlclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388693/cannot-install-mysqlclient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ubuntu, you can try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Or you can search the python dev package for your os

Comment: Thank you, I tried your method and successfully passed this error!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me with: sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev