# How to solve this `pip install mysqlclient` error?

Tags: python

My error log:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /var/www/django/crawling-api/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8g4hfjre/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8g4hfjre/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-fvvy4wq1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/django/crawling-api/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-8g4hfjre/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/var/www/django/crawling-api/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -g build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib64/ -L/usr/lib64 -lmariadb -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmariadb
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /var/www/django/crawling-api/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8g4hfjre/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8g4hfjre/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-fvvy4wq1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/django/crawling-api/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.


summary :     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmariadb
ㄴ this problem.
```

But I can't solve this problem.

Comment: The summary says, that it can't find mariadb libs. Please take a look on answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495448/unable-to-install-mysqlclient-on-centos/46495507). It is quite similar error output to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the installation instructions here: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Basically, the error message says it all. ld is a linker, it cannot find mariadb library, so you must install it. It depends on your operating system how.