# Change Django Database : SQLITE3 to MARIADB

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, mariadb

I am new to Django and python! I made a project on Django with the default database which is sqlite3. I want to now transfer the database from sqlite3 to Mariadb.

There is no data which is present in current sqlite3. I just want to know how can I transfer the default database.

I have followed the following [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04):

And added, this to my settings.py :

```
 DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
         'NAME': 'Techdevio',
         'USER': 'satharkar',
         'PASSWORD': 'root',
         'HOST': 'localhost',
         'PORT': '',
     }
 }
```

I am not sure, how things will work with this now. I am looking if someone can help me with this.
So what I did is by now :

1. I deleted the db.sqlite3 from my project folder.
2. Tried to run `python manage.py makemigrations` but it is throwing error that mysql client is not installed.

I have followed the documentation and installed everything mentioned their.
How will things work after this ?
So whenever I will try to submit the form in my django project, database, table will be created and data will be then stored under the mariadb?

I am new to all this, looking for a resolution in this case or any suggestions on how to proceed with this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't come with [`mysqlclient`](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) and hence you may need to install it by

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: I am getting so many errors by running that command :(

-> https://dpaste.org/CTH5

I am running this on centos7.  I have already installed these packages : `sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel`

Comment: I was able to download the mysqlclient now with the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495448/unable-to-install-mysqlclient-on-centos). Thanks a lot JPG.